# Is there a library for complex-valued (dense) linear algebra in OpenCL

Tags: opencl, linear-algebra

The OpenCL standard unintelligibly does not include complex numbers until today. However, some FFT implementations seem to circumvent this. Are there any (dense) linear algebra (eigenvalue solvers, linear system solver) libraries (preferably C++) out there which can deal with complex algebra, anyway?

Answer (score 3):

The reason why there is no rush to implement complex numbers in OpenCL standard (Not even 2.0 has it) is because it's quite easily doable by yourself and it doesn't concern the hardware manufacturers that much.

Here is a trivial example on how to start using complex numbers:

```
#define complex_t float2

// real part of complex product (a,b)
#define MULT_RE(a,b) (a.x * b.x - a.y*b.y)
// imaginary part of complex product (a,b)
#define MULT_IM(a,b) (a.x * b.y + a.y*b.x)

// complex product
inline complex_t mul_1(complex_t a,complex_t b)
{
  return (complex_t) (MULT_RE(a,b), MULT_IM(a,b));
}
```

As you see complex numbers map quite naturally to 2 component vectors. So whenever an algorithm happens to require complex numbers it is usually done like this.

Personally I would like to see complex numbers supported in OpenCL. But I also understand that it's mostly a convenience library instead of core feature that concerns the hardware in any way.

Comment: Totally agree, nice answer.